# Grunt uglify is using comma while minifying

Tags: gruntjs, minify

When using grunt uglify, its successfully minifying the file but all the 'use strict' for separate files are removed and replaced by comma.
Even if i use concat first and then uglify, result is same.

its coming as following;

angular.module('mymodule').controller({...}) , angular.module('mymodule').directive
and so..

Gruntfile looks like this;

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    concat: {
        options: {
            process: function(src, filepath) {
                return '//#### ' + filepath + '\n' + src;
            }
            /*separator: ';'*/
        },
        scripts: {
            src: 'public/scripts/**/*.js',
            dest: 'public/scripts/merged.js'
        }
    },
    uglify: {
        options:{
            beautify: true
        },
        scripts: {
            src: 'public/scripts/merged.js',
            dest: 'public/scripts/merged.min.js'
        }
    }
});
// load tasks
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
// register tasks
grunt.registerTask('build', ['concat', 'uglify']);
```

Do you have any idea about the fix please?

Comment: I am sorry but; what's wrong with grouping your code using commas?

Comment: I didn't test in all the browser yet but i was thinking it is going to cause some js error, isn't it? I am not sure. I thought semicolon would be required else all the files' code separated by comma will not work properly. Is that wrong?

Comment: no, the minifiers remove them and group the functions and variables and everything together... You will find semicoloumn at the very end of the file. I think the uglifier is working perfectly don't worry about that

Comment: okay. great! thanks!